# How to parse git gpgsig signed commit

Tags: git

I'm writing a Git client, which is a little tricky because there's no "Git specification", and while there is some documentation, it isn't exactly exhaustive. Essentially the git code is the specification.

My latest problem is how to parse a git commit. I thought the format was like this (EBNF):

```
commit = header* , "\n" , message ;
header = key , " " , value , "\n" ;
```

That worked until I found this commit in LLVM:

```
tree c02519f3f72b850fe67b54a2a04284b92b4947df
parent fed8c068922319cc6a84fd08e75eccf7376b21c4
author Roman Lebedev <lebedev.ri@gmail.com> 1574169814 +0300
committer Roman Lebedev <lebedev.ri@gmail.com> 1574169847 +0300
gpgsig -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

 iQIzBAABCgAdFiEEjkF6151RK40WXe2HCDw+u0oWieAFAl3T7PcACgkQCDw+u0oW
 ieAxOw//UURm9vZPv5i2qgu6Y3AKlj/jflBE8ZPrqe4CwJwmufcrMXQSAqm9i+es
 tPn7ef0iNbkz7LZlkPbJ+CileFyMg3ErsPCnJVqi2FUwxlU/sCwwUV+U0AYP+vXY
 MIXd84jh5CNJT5S9XN2Ql1Ff0mZJOD6Bfz7LT8iP8RmX9ukL+nrxG+yTx15TzW63
 5OAoBw+f47IC3jCI1QPh+F3aL8O799vmfC7tZYAguxqtgALsbGQHaz4XDFGLqTHo
 0vTZZDMG1wnw+hFUGjeDHp7FgHdhpgTQElABiCV7CpgsgnivwbNaEI6AyPXy7wj+
 4u/rPdVb19w3stN36k5Z1QAjzOcV7c7/GhAe0AfLfcKeCJOa4hllXctre8046616
 5qgTHV337gdX7DJt46Vk+8N7HVHMoSLh+QuI7koQkf1/snvrnRPSQtpTxv46RviJ
 Q/IG9T/H1JeiSZZyhHTlo3nx/NcD86tdLH3O5qZ6H99zYD1phnR8rI66TIJO6SNb
 hQ6UlbdwwW4Gt1nFdLmEp5MuXRUqWmcMhQZWKEhfZWANcUWFf2zSnnDXQK6BWkhM
 /cUH7U6F6mPMyN1y0Osh3cT8EpJNCNCGP89WDrd9o0z0Vk4Mrlon5ormskcmsf4T
 VAndfHoeMjZXWxUuMoe9Y8Hi7im0b7qKwwpGUeuJ981e6Rx/rAI=
 =8e3l
 -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

[NFC][X86] Fixup comment in CodeGen/X86/cmov.ll

As noted in post-commit review for
https://reviews.llvm.org/D59035#inline-631659
```

How should I parse this? It seems like it uses a space as the first character of each line to indicate continuation of a header value. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a header with a continuation line is indented one space, which is stripped off when determining the body of the header.  This is much like in email.

The signature is computed by removing any headers starting with `gpgsig` (e.g., `gpgsig` and the forthcoming `gpgsig-sha256`) and then using that as the data to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be as simple as parse line by line and simple assume (greedily) that until next keyword (tree, parent, author, committed etc) is found you are still getting data for the old key?

Comment: I meant "how to parse" in the sense of "how *should* I parse this". Actually writing the parser is trivial.